# Holomorphic function multiplied by real number

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I would like to ask if a holomorphic function (say $z$) multiplied by some real constant is still a holomorphic function. It seems a bit obvious but I'm searching for a good argument.

Thanks

Comment: can't you prove it using definition? its also true if you multiply it by a complex number

Comment: I believe that you only need the property that $\lim_{n\to \infty} A z_n = A\lim_{n\to \infty} z_n$ and apply that to the definition of derivative.

Comment: @NickS : what ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively: $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $f$ is complex-differentiable everywhere in its domain, if and only if the limit $$\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0}$$ exists for all $z_0$ in the domain. Now, applying a simple property of limits, note that the limit
$$\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{k \cdot f(z) - k \cdot f(z_0)}{z - z_0} = k \cdot \left( \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0} \right)$$
also always exists, for all $k \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: Indeed, one only needs the definition. The fact that a function with continuous partial derivatives which satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations is holomorphic, is non-trivial and overcomplicating the problem. This elementary answer is clearer IMO.

Comment: ($f(z)$ is complex-differentiable not $f'$)

Comment: @user1952009 that's what I was talking about.

Comment: @NickS : ??? what

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Recall the Cauchy-Riemann equation: A function
$$f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C,\quad f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+i\,v(x,y)$$
is holomorphic if and only if $u$ and $v$ are continuously differentiable and satisfy
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
.\tag{1}$$
Now multiplying $f$ by a constant means multiplying both $u$ and $v$ by the same constant, and hence the result will still satisfy (1). (The constants will cancel on both sides of each equation.)

Comment: it is not obvious to me that they consider holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ (entire) : holomorphic on an open set $U$ where for every $z \in U$, ...

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic if and only if the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied AND the partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: @Bib-lost : the continuity of the derivative is automatic when the Cauchy-Riemann equation are satisfied (i.e. when the function is complex differentiable) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Definition and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem

Comment: @user1952009 It clearly says on the article you send me: "If continuity is not a given, the converse is not necessarily true"

Comment: @Bib-lost the [Looman–Menchoff_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem) says that if $f(z)$ is complex continuous and partial differentiable and the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied on an open $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ then it is holomorphic on $U$

Comment: Fair enough, but it assumes continuity of $f$ (which is not implied by the existence of partial derivatives). Also, the Looman-Menchoff theorem is far beyond the difficulty level of the question, which was clearly asked in the context of an introduction to complex analysis.

Comment: @Bib-lost : that's a good point, what does mean $f$ is partial differentiable but maybe not continuous (or maybe not COMPLEX continuous ??) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40467/discussion-between-bib-lost-and-user1952009).

Comment: @Bib-lost let $D_v f(z)$ be the directional derivative in the direction $v$ at $z$:  $D_v f(z)=\lim_{ h \to 0, h \in [-1,1]} \frac{f(z+h v)-f(z)}{h}$. the theorem askes that $D_1 f(z)$ and $D_i f(z)$ exists for every $z \in U$. now if $f$ is not complex continuous at $z_0$ then clearly $D_1(z)$ and $D_i(z)$ are unbounded in the neighborhood of $z_0$, since $$\lim_{ h \to 0}  f(z_0+h(a+ib))-f(z) = \lim_{ h \to 0} f(z_0+h a)-f(z_0) + f(z_0+h (a+ib))-f(z_0+ah) = \lim_{ h \to 0} ha D_1(z_0) + h b D_{i}(z_0+ah)$$
which is $0$ whenever $D_{i}(z_0+ah)$ and $D_1(z_0) $ are bounded.

Comment: so the point is to see if when the partial derivatives exist and fulfill the Cauchy-Riemann equations on $U$ then $D_{i}(z)$ and $D_1(z) $ are bounded (and hence $f(z)$ is complex continuous $U$) or not.. and your example $f(z) = e^{-z^4}$ shows that the answer is "no"